# Identifiy float values in array with text strings

Tags: php, arrays, string, floating-point, php-7.3

I have an array with textstrings where I have to identify float values.
I noticed one can find numerics but not float. If I remove the quotes of the float values it works to find the float (see test $values_2).

The input data would normally come from user input [$_POST], thus the strings including both text, numerics and floats.

**Question:**

What would be the correct way to identify float values in an array with string values ?

---

**Test-1:**

```
$values_1 = [
  'text',
  '3',
  '4.5' // Cannot be found with [is_float]
];

echo is_string($values_1[0])  . "\n";
echo is_numeric($values_1[1]) . "\n";
echo is_float($values_1[2])   . "\n";
```

Returns:

```
1
1
```

---

**Test-2**

```
$values_2 = [
  'text',
  '3',
  4.5  // Found with [is_float]
];

echo is_string($values_2[0])  . "\n";
echo is_numeric($values_2[1]) . "\n";
echo is_float($values_2[2])   . "\n";
```

Returns:

```
1
1
1
```

---

Comment: Hmmm.. The title of the "Duplicate" question is misleading. The OP of that question really wanted to know why a string wasn't being cast correctly.

Comment: Albeit that one of the answers did actually answer the question.

Comment: Yes, it might be confusing at first, since this OP also deals with non-numeric values. The other question seems to imply only numeric values.

Comment: My understanding is that the suggested link, explains floats from a single variable perspective, not floats inside of an array with text strings. Updated the question to explain reason for input as string.

Comment: First check if it's numeric. If not, skip that value. If yes, use answers from other question.